# Operation $\ominus$ between Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ergodic-theory

While reading Robert Zimmer’s Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups, I ran into a notation I do not know, which I did not find explained in the book: in Chapter 2, he refers to $L^2(S)\ominus \mathbb{C}$ for a measurable space $S$. What does $\ominus$ stand for? Is it a sort of ‘direct subtraction’?

Comment: For a Hilbert space $H$ and a subspace $K\subset H$, $H\ominus K$ denotes the orthogonal complement of $K$ in $H$, i.e. the set of vectors in $H$ that are orthogonal to all vectors in $K$. In the text you encountered $\mathbb{C}$ means the a.e. constant functions.

Comment: @JonathanHole this should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: @JonathanHole thank you for your answer, I knew what the orthogonal complement is but I had never seen this notation.

Comment: @JonathanHole I was wondering if you could  tell me a reference for the notation $H\ominus K$?. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JonathanHole Are $H\ominus K$ and $K^{\perp}$ the same?

Comment: Yes, the only difference being that the former makes it explicit in which space we are taking the orthogonal complement, i.e. $H$. Note that for a closed subspace $K$ we have $H=K\oplus (H \ominus K)$ which indicates why we write $\ominus$.